# I do not know what the problem is ? Make a multiplication with entered number

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multiplication, solver, unhandled-exception

I am a newbie c# user and ı am doing some practice with w3resource.com,
it is the question: 
Write a C# Sharp program that takes a number as input and print its multiplication table:
and this is my

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number : ");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {3}", number, i, number * i);

}
```

and it says to me that the index must be greater than 0...

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

(I have translated it from Turkish to English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have index `{3}` in the `Console.WriteLine` method, but you have only 3 arguments. The argument list is zero-based.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {3}", number, i, number * i);
```

It should be

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", number, i, number * i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int i;
        String n;
        Console. Write("Enter any Value for Table Multiplication : ");
        n = Console. ReadiLine();

        int x = Convert.ToInt32(n);
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
        Console. Write("{0} X {1} = {2} ", x, i, (x *i));
        Console. Read(); }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).